# What causes tendon microinjuries to become painful in the case of a tendinosis?

Tags: pain, tendinopathy

From http://www.tendonpain.org/injury.shtml:

> Tendinosis/tendinopathy is a chronic degenerative tendon injury that is usually brought on by repetitive motion. The repetitive motion is often associated with activities in the workplace or with sports. Microinjuries gradually accumulate faster than they can heal until the area eventually becomes painful.

From {1}:

> The term “lateral epicondylitis” is a misnomer
>   because, pathologically, this condition
>   consists of mucoid degeneration
>   with a paucity of acute or chronic inflammatory
>   cells. The condition is, therefore,
>   more appropriately referred to as “tendinosis.”
>   It is believed that tendinosis is the
>   result of repetitive trauma causing microtearing
>   of the tendon. Scar tissue
>   forms during the healing process, which is then subjected to further tearing with
>   repeat trauma (1,3,7). Eventually, as the
>   cycle of injury and repair continues, the
>   patient will become symptomatic.

From http://www.tendinopathyrehab.com/blog/tendinopathy-updates/how-useful-is-imaging-in-tendinopathy-infographic:

[image]

I wonder what causes tendon microinjuries to eventually become painful in the case of a tendinosis. I.e., how comes pain from a tendinopathy often suddenly appears one day even though the microinjuries accumulated over the preceding weeks didn't create any pain at the time.

I am mostly interested in the tendons that attach to the epicondyles of the humerus.

---

References:

- {1} Levin, Dayna, Levon N. Nazarian, Theodore T. Miller, Patrick L. O'Kane, Rick I. Feld, Laurence Parker, and John M. McShane. "Lateral Epicondylitis of the Elbow: US Findings 1." Radiology 237, no. 1 (2005): 230-234. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=8668317182298519154&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22 ; http://dx.doi.org/10.1148/radiol.2371040784; http://sci-hub.cc/10.1148/radiol.2371040784

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.